# io.cucumber.junit.UndefinedStepException

Tags: java, cucumber, cucumber-junit

I have created cucumber with junit project and while running the project iam facing "
io.cucumber.junit.UndefinedStepException" error . I have given both my test runner and pom xml
file below for references,

Hi-I have created cucumber with junit project and while running the project iam facing "
io.cucumber.junit.UndefinedStepException" error . I have given both my test runner and pom xml
file below for references,
Hi-I have created cucumber with junit project and while running the project iam facing "
io.cucumber.junit.UndefinedStepException" error . I have given both my test runner and pom xml
file below for references,

***below is my test runner class***

```
package testRunner;

import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import io.cucumber.junit.Cucumber;
import io.cucumber.junit.CucumberOptions;



@RunWith(Cucumber.class)

@CucumberOptions(
        features = "src/test/resources/features/SF_CRMAccount.feature",//tags= {"@run"},
                 glue = {"src/test/java/stepdefinitions"}, 
                 dryRun =false,
                 plugin= {"pretty","html:target/test-output/index.html","com.aventstack.extentreports.cucumber.adapter.ExtentCucumberAdapter:",
                         "timeline:test-output/"},
                 publish = true,
                 monochrome = true
)

public class TestRunner {

}
```

***below is my pom xml:***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>salesforce_CRM</groupId>
  <artifactId>salesforce_CRM</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

  <name>salesforce_CRM</name>
  <!-- FIXME change it to the project's website -->
  <url>http://www.example.com</url>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.7</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.7</maven.compiler.target>
  </properties>

<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>mulesoft-releases</id>
        <name>MuleSoft Repository</name>
        <url>https://repository.mulesoft.org/nexus/content/repositories/public/</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>

  <dependencies>
            <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/junit/junit -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.12</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
          <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.cucumber/cucumber-core -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-core</artifactId>
            <version>6.10.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.cucumber/cucumber-html -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-html</artifactId>
            <version>0.2.7</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.sourceforge.cobertura/cobertura -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sourceforge.cobertura</groupId>
            <artifactId>cobertura</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.cucumber/cucumber-java -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
            <version>6.10.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.cucumber/cucumber-junit -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>
            <version>6.10.4</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
            
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.cucumber/cucumber-jvm-deps -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-jvm-deps</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.6</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.masterthought/cucumber-reporting -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.masterthought</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-reporting</artifactId>
        <version>5.5.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hamcrest/hamcrest-core -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
        <artifactId>hamcrest-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.2</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.cucumber/gherkin -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
        <artifactId>gherkin</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-java -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
        <version>3.141.59</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.sun/tools -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun</groupId>
        <artifactId>tools</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.0</version>
        <scope>system</scope>
        <systemPath>C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_291\lib\tools.jar</systemPath>
    </dependency>
<!--  this is for reporting dependencies -->        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>tech.grasshopper</groupId>
            <artifactId>extentreports-cucumber6-adapter</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    <dependency>
    <groupId>com.github.ralfstuckert.pdfbox-layout</groupId>
    <artifactId>pdfbox2-layout</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.pdfbox</groupId>
    <artifactId>pdfbox</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.22</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
             <groupId>com.github.javafaker</groupId>
             <artifactId>javafaker</artifactId>
             <version>1.0.2</version>
        </dependency>
         <dependency>
                 <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
                 <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
                 <version>4.1.2</version>
          </dependency>
          <dependency>
                 <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
                 <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
                 <version>4.1.2</version>
          </dependency>
          <dependency>
                 <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
                 <artifactId>poi-ooxml-schemas</artifactId>
                 <version>4.1.2</version>
          </dependency>
          <dependency>
                 <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
                 <artifactId>poi-scratchpad</artifactId>
                 <version>4.1.2</version>
          </dependency>
          <dependency>
                 <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
                 <artifactId>ooxml-schemas</artifactId>
                 <version>1.4</version>
          </dependency>

          <dependency>
                 <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
                 <artifactId>openxml4j</artifactId>
                 <version>1.0-beta</version>
          </dependency>
        <dependency>
    <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.0</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
    <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.3</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.7.5</version>
</dependency>
        
    <dependency>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
    <version>1.7.5</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
    <artifactId>cucumber-core</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.8</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.17</version>
        </dependency>
        
        
<!-- Thanks for using https://jar-download.com -->
        
  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <pluginManagement><!-- lock down plugins versions to avoid using Maven defaults (may be moved to parent pom) -->
      <plugins>
        <!-- clean lifecycle, see https://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/lifecycles.html#clean_Lifecycle -->
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.1.0</version>
        </plugin>
        <!-- default lifecycle, jar packaging: see https://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/default-bindings.html#Plugin_bindings_for_jar_packaging -->
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.0.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.8.0</version>
          <configuration>
    <source>1.8</source>
    <target>1.8</target>
    </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.22.1</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.0.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.5.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.8.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <!-- site lifecycle, see https://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/lifecycles.html#site_Lifecycle -->
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-site-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.7.1</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-project-info-reports-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.0.0</version>
        </plugin>
      </plugins>

    </pluginManagement>
  </build>
</project>
```

Answer (score 0):

The "glue" in Cucumber relates to the glue code and when defining `@CucumberOptions` you need to define packages rather than directories.

That is:

```
glue = {"stepdefinitions"}
```